# Landscape and portrait mode for android application

Tags: android

I want to create my android application for both landscape and portrait mode.

I have created two folder layout and layout-land and defined two xml for each activity.

All the activities are working fine.

In all the activities it automatically adjust the rotation but in one activity i have used onconfigurationchange method.

Now my one more activity is creating problem.i have implemented google map and called two threads in that activity.Threads call an API which fetch data from server.

On starting its working well but after 8 or 10 orientation application gets crashed.Please someone help me to resolve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Landscape and portrait mode for application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152757/landscape-and-portrait-mode-for-application)

Comment: "but after 8 or 10 orientation application gets crashed" -- use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "crash".

Comment: We can't debug your code if you don't post logs or the code itself. But my guess is that your threads are holding onto an old version of your activity/context and thus crash.

Comment: the error is:64420 bytes allocation is too much for this process.

Answer (score 0):

just try the following code in manifest for your Activity

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
```

and Let me know

Comment: i have already done this but it shows error when i switch to landscape mode.

Comment: i did this again now and it rotates automatically but it shows portrait view of application.